# NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException (NSLayoutConstraint) iOS5

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I'm getting a `NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException` on the **iPhone** 5.1 Simulator.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', 
reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'
```

Everything works fine on iOS6 and on the **iPad** 5.1 Simulator.

The thing is I'm **not** using NSLayoutConstraints in my Project nor does it contain any **Nib**-Files!

Any sugestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set a global exceptions breakpoint and see where it's throwing this.  If it's somewhere deep in machine code, then file a bug with Apple because we can't do anything.  If it shows up in your code, then you're not telling us the whole story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what it was, but uninstalling and reinstalling the app did the trick (a "clean" didn't by the way).